# What are these weird boxes in Eclipse/Aptana Studio

Tags: eclipse, ide, radrails

Does anyone know what these really annoying boxes surrounding random code are in Eclipse? I've seen them come, go, grab the beginning and end of a word, I have no idea what they are supposed to mean. I'd really like to turn off the "feature" or figure out what they mean at least. Thanks![image]

Comment: Isn't there a hole lot of customization options for the editor appearance, i.e. syntax highlighting and so on, in the preferences dialog? There you can set up colors, or surrounding rectangles, or whiggles, for most of all highlightings/markers.

Comment: Yes, and I'm afraid that I may have enabled these buggers by messing around in those settings. I just can't come up with a rational explanation for what they are marking so I can find a way to disable/change them.

Comment: There should be a 'reset' button. I´ll take a look later, no eclipse at hand.

Answer (score 2):

This is for Aptana 3.2.1 on Mac, working with HTML.

To disable the boxes that encompass entire matching html tags:

preferences > general > editors > html tag pair occurrences; then uncheck "text as box."

Then, to disable the boxes around the matching angle brackets themselves:

preferences > aptana studio > editors; then uncheck "colorize matching character pairs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in Windows with Aptana studio 3 you can turn it off this way:

**Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations**

Inside there you find a box and select **HTML Tag Pair Occurrences**. Uncheck the box **Text as**.

However you also loose the good thing you get when you select a tag and it shows the matching tag. That's why I don't uncheck the box. Instead I chose Text as **Vertical bar**. It is easier to look at. Maybe you will also have to fiddle with Occurrences in the Annotations menu.

I think this is very bad done when they developed Aptana Studio. Who wants those default boxes? But I really do want to have the matching tag selected when I select one of them.

Comment: Thank you for this!